# PostgreSQL/PostGIS Metadata - with QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, metadata, inspire

I'm stuck trying to get metadata for vector-layers into a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS-Extension. The ESRI-Environment allows to define metadata (ISO, FGDC, INSPIRE,...) and saves this information together with the features e.g. in Oracle, FGDB, Shape/XML,...). QGIS provides metadata-properties for layers, but these don't find their way into PG.

Does someone know a solution to save metadata together with the features in PG (based on the common standards)?

Comment: What does speak against creating the needed attributes in your feature table or a joined table? You don´t really need an extra tool for it.

Comment: ..have a look at [gis.se:40994](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40994/standard-for-storing-human-metadata-in-spatial-databases)

Comment: Can you give more information on how Esri stores INSPIRE metadata for a shapefile, are you saying it provides a tool to link the shapefile to metadata stored in a database?  Or does it store the XML in the same folder as the shapefile (that is not in a database)?

Comment: Hi! Due to holidays I will check it next week - normally ArcGIS stores Metadata fpr SHPs as a XML-File (same Filename). In Databases it stores Metadata natively within the database (but I have to do a deeper look in it).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to store some metadata, you can customize the metadata model to be complient with INSPIRE, ISO, etc

https://docs.3liz.org/qgis-pgmetadata-plugin/

The presentation
https://youtu.be/IaIIGHuogwM